# Asp.Net Core 2 Convert FileMultipartSection to IFormFile

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I'm working on a project with another team and they made a class library that I have to use. In one of the methods, they receive a list of `IFormFile`, but in my upload endpoint, due to performance issues, I do the upload using `MultipartReader`.

My problem is that I'm having a hard time trying to convert `FileMultipartSection` to `IFormFile`. I have already seem [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfile?view=aspnetcore-2.0) but I still don't get how to get properties like `.ContentType` from `FileMultipartSection`. Here is the code where I'm trying to get it to work ([reference here](http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/pawel/2017/03/aspnet-core-webapi-performance.html)):

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> UploadMultipartUsingReader()
        {
            var boundary = GetBoundary(Request.ContentType);
            var reader = new MultipartReader(boundary, Request.Body, 80 * 1024);

            var valuesByKey = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            MultipartSection section;

            var files = new List<FileMultipartSection>();
            //var files = new List<IFormFile>();

            while ((section = await reader.ReadNextSectionAsync()) != null)
            {
                var contentDispo = section.GetContentDispositionHeader();

                if (contentDispo.IsFileDisposition())
                {
                    var fileSection = section.AsFileSection();
                    var bufferSize = 32 * 1024;
                    await HelperFunctions.ReadStream(fileSection.FileStream, bufferSize);
                    files.Add(fileSection); // HERE I should add a convertion from  FileMultipartSection to   IFormFile

                }
                else if (contentDispo.IsFormDisposition())
                {
                    var formSection = section.AsFormDataSection();
                    var value = await formSection.GetValueAsync();
                    valuesByKey.Add(formSection.Name, value);
                }
            }
        return Ok();
    }
```

Is it possible to do this conversion? If so, How can I do it?
Thanks for any help

---

UPDATE
I also tried like this and it seems to fail. it lacks properties:

```
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                await fileSection.FileStream.CopyToAsync(ms);
                Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.FormFile ifile = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.FormFile(ms, 0, ms.Length, fileSection.Name, fileSection.FileName);
                files.Add(ifile);
            }
```

Comment: I know this is an old question, but what exactly do you mean by "lacks properties"?